# SassError: expected selector

Tags: reactjs, sass, create-react-app

```js
import React from 'react';
import {
  Link
} from 'react-router-dom';
import '../../components/Button/button.sass';
import './Main.sass';
// import Button from '../Button/button';
import PhotoOne from '../../assets/yoga_photos/Yoga1.jpg';
import YogaClass from '../../assets/yoga_photos/Yoga15.jpg';
import PhotoFive from '../../assets/yoga_photos/Yoga5.jpg';

function Main(props) {
  return ( <
    div >
    <
    div className = "home-container" >
    <
    section className = "hero"
    id = "hero-image" >
    <
    div className = "flex-center-col content-container" >
    <
    h1 > Build Your Yoga Class < /h1> <
    p > Put your class together today < /p> <
    div >
    <
    button className = "button-outlined" >
    <
    Link to = {
      '/about'
    } > Learn More < /Link> <
    /button> <
    button className = {
      "button-solid"
    } >
    <
    Link to = {
      '/register'
    } > Start Building < /Link> <
    /button> <
    /div> <
    /div> <
    /section> <
    section className = "get-started flex-center-col" >
    <
    h1 > Loving it is easy < /h1> <
    div className = "flex-center-row" >
    <
    div className = "headings flex-center-col " >
    <
    img className = "lg-dot"
    src = {
      YogaClass
    }
    alt = "Yoga Class" > < /img> <
    h2 > Create < /h2> <
    p > Create yoga sequences
    for a class or personal use. < /p> <
    /div> <
    div className = "headings flex-center-col " >
    <
    img className = "lg-dot"
    src = {
      PhotoFive
    }
    alt = "Yoga with IPad" > < /img> <
    h2 > Customize < /h2> <
    p > 48 poses to choose from. < /p> <
    /div> <
    div className = "headings flex-center-col " >
    <
    img className = "lg-dot"
    src = {
      PhotoOne
    }
    alt = "Yoga Pose" > < /img> <
    h2 > Save and Share < /h2> <
    p > Create and save up to 10 sequences. < /p> <
    /div> <
    /div> <
    div id = "center-btn" >
    <
    button className = {
      "button-solid"
    } >
    <
    Link to = {
      '/register'
    } > Start Building < /Link> <
    /button> <
    /div> <
    /section> <
    section className = "content content-bg-img" >
    <
    div className = "flex-center-col content-container" >
    <
    h1 > How It Works < /h1> <
    div className = "flex-center-row" >
    <
    span className = "sm-dot" > < /span> { /* <img className="sm-dot" src={} alt="yoga pose image" ></img> */ } <
    div className = "how-it-works" >
    <
    h2 > Step 1 < /h2> <
    p > Sign up
    for a new account. < /p> <
    p > lorem ipsom lorem ipsom < /p> <
    /div> <
    /div> <
    div className = "flex-center-row" >
    <
    span className = "sm-dot" > < /span> { /* <img className="sm-dot" src={} alt="yoga pose image" ></img> */ } <
    div className = "how-it-works" >
    <
    h2 > Step 2 < /h2> <
    p > Create your first yoga sequence < /p> <
    p > lorem ipsom lorem ipsom < /p> <
    /div> <
    /div> <
    div className = "flex-center-row" >
    <
    span className = "sm-dot" > < /span> { /* <img className="sm-dot" src={} alt="yoga pose image" ></img> */ } <
    div className = "how-it-works" >
    <
    h2 > Step 3 < /h2> <
    p > Save it and do yoga < /p> <
      p > lorem ipsom lorem ipsom < /p> <
      /div> <
      /div> <
      div id = "content-bt" >
      <
      button className = {
        "button-solid"
      } >
      <
      Link to = {
        '/register'
      } > Build Your First Class < /Link> <
      /button> <
      /div> <
      /div> <
      /section> <
      /div> <
      /div>
  )
}

export default Main;
```

```css
$DarkTeal: #05bc65
$LightTeal: #afe1e5
$Fushia: #b62769
$DarkGray: #545454
$LightGray: #d4d7d7

$image-path: "../../assets/yoga_photos"

.flex-center-col 
    display: flex
    flex-direction: column
    justify-content: center
    align-items: stretch
    align-content: center

.flex-center-row
    display: flex
    flex-direction: row
    justify-content: center
    align-items: center
    align-content: center
    
.home-container
    display: block
    width: 100%

.home-container h1
    font-size: 2em


.content-container p
    color:  black

// *******  Hero  ********** //
.hero
    width: 100%
    height: 500px

    button 
        margin: 30px
    
// *******  End Hero ******** //

.headings
    margin-left: 40px
    margin-right: 40px

#hero-image
    background-color: $LightGray
    background:linear-gradient(0deg rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)) url("/assets/yoga_photos/Yoga19.jpg")
    background-size: cover

.content-container
    width: 100%
    height: 100%

// ******** Get Started  ********* //
.get-started
    height: 600px
    width: 100%

.lg-dot
    height: 300px
    width: 300px
    background-color: #bbb
    border-radius: 50%
    display: inline-block

.headings p
    width: 300px
    text-align: center

// ******** End Get Started  ********* //

// ******** Three Easy Steps  ********* //


.sm-dot
    height: 100px
    width: 100px
    background-color: #bbb
    border-radius: 50%
    display: inline-block

.content
    background-color: $LightTeal
    width: 100%
    height: 600px

.content-bg-img
    background-color: $LightGray
    background:linear-gradient(0deg,rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)) url(#{$image-path}/Yoga18.jpg)
    background-size: cover
.how-it-works
    margin-left: 2em
    width: 200px

#content-bt
    margin-top: 1em
#center-btn
    margin 0 auto
```

[image]

I am attempting to update an older project that has some corrupted files in the node_modules dir.  I attempted to fix those files and finally just deleted it and reinstalled. This fixed that issue. But, now Sass is throwing me this error. I am not adept enough at sass to know why. Can't seem to find any solutions on Stack Overflow.

```
|_src
| |_assets
| | |_yoga_photos
| |_components
```

I have read a bunch about using webpack to fix this?  But, I am using create react app to avoid that.  I do have node-sass installed. Let me know if more context is required.

Comment: Can you share the code that causes this error?

Comment: Code added.  Let me know if there is anything else you need to see.